# Overloaded Template Function Help - C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading

I keep getting an error "no instance of overloaded function "printArray" matches the argument list. Will someone please tell me why? I'm trying to overload a template function so that it displays elements of an array starting and ending at specified positions.

I have my initial template and function:

```
template< typename T >
void printArray( const T *array, int count )
```

And the function that I'm trying to overload.

```
template< typename T >
void printArray(int lowSubscript, int highSubscript)
```

and my call:

```
// display elements 1-3 of array a
   cout << "Array a from positions 1 to 3 is:\n";
   elements = printArray(1,3);
```

my call for the first printArray shows no errors:

```
// display array a using original printArray function
   cout << "\nUsing original printArray function\n";
   printArray( a, ACOUNT );
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an array passed in to the second `printArray` (and `elements` is being assigned the value returned from a function that has return type `void`).

Comment: Post the error message including the types in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second overload of `printArray` is a template, but the signature is not dependent on the template parameter `T`. Therefore you must specify it when calling, e.g. `printArray<int>(1,3)`.

However, it is unclear which array is being printed: did you forget to add a parameter for the array, e.g. `printArray(a,1,3)`? In which case, you might be able to have `T` deduced from that parameter, as it is in the `printArray(a,count)` version.

Also, the return type of `void` means you cannot write `elements=printArray(1,3)` even if the template parameter could be deduced.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Your second `printArray` does not use T, and thus should not be a template.

The reason the compiler does not recognize it as a candidate is because it can not deduce T.